# Trivial Topology and Basis

Tags: general-topology

I recently started studying topology (Royden and Fitzpatrick's Real Analysis - 4th edition) and I stumbled upon this exercise:

**"Show that the trivial (indiscrete) topology on a set $\, X \,$ has a unique base."**

Consider a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$, where $\mathcal{T} = \{\, \varnothing, \,X \, \}$.

My first reaction was "The unique base obviously is $\mathcal{B}_1 = \{X \}$". But the more a thought about it, the more it became apparent that $\mathcal{B}_2 = \{\, \varnothing, \,X \, \}$ could also be a base. So, now, I'm wondering if it is something definitional that I'm missing. The way the book defines a base is as follows:

**Definition:** For a topological space $(X, \mathcal{T})$ and a point $x \in X$, a collection of neighborhoods of $x$, $\mathcal{B}_x$ is called a **base for the topology at $x$** if for any neighborhood $A$ of $x$, there is $B \in \mathcal{B}_x$ such that $B \subseteq A$. A collection of open sets $\mathcal{B}$ is called a **base for the topology $\mathcal{T}$** provided it contains a base for the topology at each point $x$.

Note that considering  $\mathcal{B}_1$ or $\mathcal{B}_2$, which are both collections of open sets of $\mathcal{T}$, for any arbitrary $x \in X$ we can define a collection of neighborhoods of $x$,   $\mathcal{B}_x = \{ X \}$. Then considering any neighborhood $A$ of $x$ (In this case the only possible neighborhood is $A = X$, we can take $X \in \mathcal{B}_x$ and it is clear that $X \subseteq X$. By definition this would imply that there is not a unique base for $\mathcal{T}$, in fact both $\mathcal{B}_1$ and $\mathcal{B}_2$ are basis for this topology.

If anyone can point out the error I made in my explanation, or (preferably) side with my answer, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen the empty set included as a basic open set in a topology, but I'm not sure there's a reason why it couldn't...at heart, that's what the question here is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One definition of a basis is a set $\mathcal{B}$ is a subset of $\mathcal{T}$ such that every member of $\mathcal{T}$ is a union of members of $\mathcal{B}$. This is equivalent to your definition *if* you allow the empty union. The only thing I can think is that this author does not, but that contradicts their own definition. If you don't allow the empty union, then clearly the empty set is mandatory.

Comment: He doesn't comment on the empty union convention, but he states this proposition:  Let $(\, X, \, \mathcal{T})$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{B}$ be a subcollection of the topology. Then $\mathcal{B}$ is a base for the topology if, and only if, every nonempty open set is the union of a subcollection of $\mathcal{B}$. Thinking about it now it seems to agree with my interpretation.